# Perturbation theory without closure relation

Tags: perturbation-theory

I have learnt how to do perturbation theory in both degenerate and non-degenerate cases. However, since I have been doing quantum mechanics, and the operators (in finite dimensional situations, they are simply matrices) I have been playing with they all admit a complete basis formed by eigenvectors (what we call a closure relation in quantum mechanics). However, I am not sure what we can do if the closure relation no longer holds. I have never seen any text illustrating how to do that. For instance, if we want to solve the perturbation problem
$$A+\epsilon B$$ with $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$
There is only one non-zero eigenvector of $A$ and so we cannot form a basis with eigenvectors (the closure relation fails). What can we do in this situation?
Of course, I am asking for a general solution instead of this $2\times 2$ example, which can be directly and easily solved.

Comment: It's not true that there's only one non-zero eigenvector of $A$. There's only one eigenvector for a non-zero eigenvalue, but an eigenvalue being zero doesn't cause a problem. You still have two linearly independent eigenvectors that form a basis of the space. (I'm not writing this as an answer because I don't know whether it answers your question or merely points out an error in your toy example. In the latter case, can you give an example you'd like to be able to solve where you actually don't have a basis of eigenvectors? This shouldn't usually occur in quantum mechanics.)

Comment: @joriki Thanks for pointing it out. How about this one with $A$ being $[0, -1, 2; 0, 1, -1; 0, -1, 1]$ and B being $[0, 0, 1; 0, 1, 0; 1, 0, 0]$? Numerically result shows that the eigenvalues $0$ will split into two branches as perturbation is turned on and they scale like $\sqrt{\epsilon}$, which is definitely not something I have seen on textbook.

Comment: This $A$ isn't Hermitian, so it shouldn't be the unperturbed Hamiltonian in a quantum-mechanical system. Are you asking this question more generally about the eigenvalues of arbitrary perturbed matrices? (If so, you should perhaps make that clearer in the question; it wasn't clear to me.)

Comment: @joriki If the matrix is Hermitian, it must have a complete basis of eigenvectors, as required by the spectral theorem. Thus, only non-symmetric (non-Hermitian in the complex case) matrices can have the singularity I look for.

Comment: Yes, certainly, I just misunderstood your question because it sounded to me like you were asking about quantum-mechanical perturbation theory. I'll delete my comments so they don't distract from your question. As I wrote, I'd suggest that you edit the question to make it more clear that you're interested in general eigenvalue perturbation and the part about quantum mechanics is just motivation for the question.